# Changing style attributes of Previous state in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Currently I am using a useState to add a border for an image with each click. When I click on an image it gives me a border correctly, but when I click on another image it retains the previous images state and keeps it active. What I want is when I press on a image, the previous image which was clicked should remove it's border and the new Image should have the border. This is the code I used so far where each click adds a border to the image:

```
const ListItem = (props) => { 

const [background, setBackground] = useState(true);
  const setStyle = (background) => {
    setBackground(background);
  }
  
  const { itemWidth } = props;

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <Animated.View
      style={{
          margin: 5,
        }}>
        <View onClick={() => setBackground(current => !current)}
         style={{borderWidth: background? 0:1,
            borderColor: '#000',}}>
        <Image
          style={{
            width: itemWidth,
            height: 50,
          }}
          source={props.image}></Image>
          </View>
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
```

Here is where I populate my images from:

Images.js:

```
export default class BottomImages extends Component { 

state = {
    columns: 3,
  };

  render() {
    const { columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={columns}
          data={[
            require('../resource/images/AzureDamsel.png'),
            require('../resource/images/BicolourAngelfish.png'),
            require('../resource/images/ClownTriggerfish.png'),
          ]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <ListItem
                itemWidth={(ITEM_WIDTH - 10 * columns) / columns}
                image={item}
              />
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(index) => {
            return index;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've also added a sandbox for reference if needed: [Sandbox Code](https://snack.expo.dev/@jay_m/paranoid-carrot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this managing the active image id.

The basic idea here is to add an unique Id to every image. And Keep one Active Id to track which image is currectly clicked.

```
state = {
    columns: 3,
    activeItemIndex: -1
  };
```

Flatlist should look like -

```
<FlatList
          numColumns={columns}
          data={[{
            id: 1,
            image: require('../resource/images/AzureDamsel.png')
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            image: require('../resource/images/BicolourAngelfish.png')
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            image: require('../resource/images/ClownTriggerfish.png')
          }]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <ListItem
                itemWidth={(ITEM_WIDTH - 10 * columns) / columns}
                image={item.image}
                itemIndex={item.id}
                activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
                onChangeActiveItemIndex={(index)=>{
                  this.setState({
                    activeItemIndex: index
                  })
                }}
              />
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(index) => {
            return index;
          }}
        />
```

I modified the code and here is updated [Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@agabhane/paranoid-carrot).
The code is not working exactly the way it should work. But i hope you got the idea.

Comment: Yea this kinda worked out. But not exactly what I wanted since I have to sometimes double tap on it. Any chance I can do the same with the Swiper component I have above the images. For example if it slides to Slide 2, then border of second image gets active?